# Migration from MVC2 2008 application to MVC3 2010

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

My MVC2 application is on VS2008. I need to convert to MVC3 2010. Can any one help me on this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

try to use this tool it's work fine but you need to sure that they built in MVC 2 
the tool can be found on http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2010/07/28/migrating-asp-net-mvc-2-applications-to-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx